# sub query returns more than 1 - issue with passing values into subquery

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I am running the following query which keep stating that more then one row is given:

```
select filestorage.id 
from `filestorage` 
where (SELECT LEFT(filestorage_inst_data.value, length(filestorage_inst_data.value - 1)) as seconds
        FROM filestorage_inst_data 
        WHERE filestorage_inst_data.parameter = "Time" AND filestorage_inst_data.filestorage_id = filestorage.id) <= 3600
```

For some reason, the only very first value is passed into the subquery. Also, if I do set a limit within the subquery than the data is fetched fine, it's just I don't see why query would fetch multiple results?

Comment: i have adjusted the statement

Comment: provide some sample data and ur expected output format

Comment: Have you consider adding `LIMIT 1` if your where clause returns `more then one row`

Comment: limit 1 does the job, it just feels like a hack;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT filestorage.id 
FROM filestorage f
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM filestorage_inst_data fid
             WHERE fid.parameter = 'Time' 
               AND fid.filestorage_id = f.id 
               AND CAST(LEFT(fid.value, length(fid.value - 1)) AS UNSIGNED) <= 3600)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a specific one row when giving a select statement on where clause.  select clause that, the one you using on where clause must return one unique row. for example.

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE role_id=(SELECT role_id FROM user_role WHERE role_name='Admin');"
```